# upper left as well as upper right triangle

Tags: java, string

I want to insert blank spaces as shown in required output

`input string :abc`

required output:

```
abcabc
ab--bc
a----c
```

But mine comes as:

```
abcabc
abbc
ac
```

---

```
public static void triangle(String s){

    int length = s.length();

    for(int i=0;i<2*length;i++){
        System.out.println();

        for(int j=0;j<length-i;j++){
            System.out.print(" "+s.charAt(j));
        }                   
        for(int k=i;k<length;k++){
            System.out.print(" "+s.charAt(k));      
        }    
    }
}
```

Comment: Always do a dry run of your algo. The mistakes will come out on its own. Once you get the proper answer to your question, you have to accept the answer or vote it up if you are satisfied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or just for loops :)

```
for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < s.length()-i; j++) {
        System.out.print(s.charAt(j));
    }
    for (int j = s.length()-i; j < s.length(); j++) {
        System.out.print(" ");
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
        System.out.print(" ");
    }
    for (int j = i; j < s.length(); j++) {
        System.out.print(s.charAt(j));

    }
    System.out.println("");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    public static void triangle(String s){
    int length = s.length();
    for(int i=0;i<length;i++){
        System.out.println();
        int j=0;
            while(j<length-i){
                System.out.print(s.charAt(j));
                j++;
            }
            while(j<length){
                System.out.print(" ");
                j++;
            }
        int k=0;
        while(k<i){
            System.out.print(" ");
            k++;
        }
        while(k<length){
                System.out.print(s.charAt(k));
                k++;
        }
 }}
```

Put it under while loops.